# What are the advantages of using Builder over regular xml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

I have a Rails application which is using the Builder gem for writing easy to use XML files.

I am very much satisfied with the Builder gem but, as per my product architect's view, we should always use simple .xml files instead of using third party tools.

So, I need to give a solid justification to him explaining to him about the advantages of using Builder over regular XML files in our Rails application.

Can anyone give or guide me to a valid justification on the usage of Builder over regualr RXML/XML files in a Rails application?

Answer (score 1):

If your xml files are static than he is correct and there is no benefit of friting them using any sort of xml template. If you are using it for dynamic content than you gain all of the benefit of template language such as sharing the code between templates, caching etc

Answer (score 1):

He can be as high minded as he likes, but Builder 3.0 comes with any brand new rails 3 app. It's already in your gem bundle, why not utilize it? It's like saying ActiveRecord or JQuery shouldn't be used because we shouldn't rely on a third party tool. Since you're already using rails and all of the open source software that comes with it, what's wrong with Builder?

That being said, as Yuiry pointed out, the advantage is that builder is dynamic whereas a .xml is static.